# Write Fedora.iso to USB and boot it from a Macbook

Tags: linux, mac, usb, fedora, iso-image

I have an .iso image of the full Fedora 16 install (Downloaded from http://fedoraproject.org/en/get-fedora-options#formats as "Fedora 16 DVD")
and the question now is: How do I write it on a USB stick, so I can install it on my Mac book?

I tried using DD as the install guide said, and that gave me a USB stick which can boot from my PC. But it can't boot from the Mac (The Mac start menu don't show it as a boot option).

Edit:
I downloaded a live install image, and did this (SSD is my USB 4GB thing)

```
/sbin/mkdosfs -F 32 -n usbdisk /dev/dev/sdd1

sudo livecd-iso-to-disk --format --reset-mbr --efi /tmp/download/Fedora-16-i686-Live-KDE.iso /dev/sdd1
```

And this produced an image which can boot on my pc but not on my mac. This seems to indicate that the `--efi` is not working, because if it really was EFI it would not boot on a normal pc, would it?

I then tried this: (Difference being that I write the image directory to /dev/sdd instead of /dev/sdd1) but this still will not boot on the Mac (it newer shows up at the startup screen on the Mac).

```
sudo livecd-iso-to-disk --format --reset-mbr --efi /tmp/download/Fedora-
```

PS: My host Linux is Fedora 13.

Answer (score -1):

use liveusb-creater it is a software for creating live usb, or see http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB

Comment: But the documentation say that this only work for the live image. The 3.5GB image I downloaded is the install image, not a live image.

Comment: Oh it seems there is some conflicting documentation. The documentation you linked say: "The livecd-iso-to-disk method also works with DVD install iso images, even though these are not Live images." so I will try use it and repport back :}

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Okay i make some investigation and seems like only from Fedora 17 there is EFI boot support so you won't be able to boot Fedora 16.

source: http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/12037.html

I only found this article that can be useful:
http://fedorasolved.org/Members/jmontleon/installing-fedora-16-on-macbooks-using-grub2-efi

it's a very HARD job, you will probably want to avoid this and install Fedora 17+.

Comment: Please read the UNetbootin documentation: *"Note that Live USB drives are bootable only on PCs (not on Macs)."*

Comment: that's not true, on my macbook pro 2010 OSX 10.8.4 yesterday i boot Gparted created with unebootin without problem (EFI boot)

Comment: Can you maybe try booting Fedora? It'd be appreciated if you could [edit] your post to include a little more context than just a link (and also capitalize the I properly), and quickly describe how to create the bootable version. Thanks.