# Is it possible to install Linux straight from an ISO image?

Tags: linux, macbook-air

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Write Fedora.iso to USB and boot it from a Macbook](https://superuser.com/questions/370366/write-fedora-iso-to-usb-and-boot-it-from-a-macbook)

I have a Macbook Air without an optical disk drive. I do not have a USB optical drive handy.

Is there any way I can perform an installation of Fedora using the ISO image without burning it?

Comment: If you have a USB memory stick handy: [How do I burn an ISO on a USB drive on Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/63654/how-do-i-burn-an-iso-on-a-usb-drive-on-mac-os-x)

Comment: You can make a bootable usb, altough there seem to be problems with booting from usb stick on macbook http://superuser.com/questions/27794/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-on-a-mac http://superuser.com/questions/370366/write-fedora-iso-to-isb-and-boot-it-from-a-macbook

Comment: Yes you can, if you go to pendrivelinux they have many tutorials on this.

Comment: Have you tried with VirtualBox?